# Javascript balanced function is defined according to console but undefined according to function call. What's the scope feature I'm bungling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, balanced-payments

I am trying to create a user credit card via balanced.js.

In the javascript console, when I type "balanced.card.create" I get back the balanced.card.create function.

But when I balanced.card.create(payload, handleCreditCardResponse) I get undefined.

Code:

In my html header I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://js.balancedpayments.com/1.1/balanced.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="localbalancedcode.js"></script>
```

In localbalancedcode.js to the form submit event I have:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#create-credit-card-submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var payload = {
        name: $('#id_name').val(),
        address: $('#id_address').val(),
        city: $('#id_city').val(),
        line1: $('#id_line1').val(),
        line2: $('#id_line2').val(),
        state: $('#id_state').val(),
        postal_code: $('#id_postal_code').val(),
        number: $('#id_number').val(),
        expiration_month: $('#id_expiration_month').val(),
        expiration_year: $('#id_expiration_year').val(),
        cvv: $('#id_cvv').val()
    };
    // Create credit card
    balanced.card.create(payload, handleCreditCardResponse);
});
});
```

And I have the callback function:

```
function handleCreditCardResponse(response) {
if (response.status_code === 201) {
    debugger
    var fundingInstrument = response.cards[0];
    // Call your backend
    jQuery.post("user/payment/card/add/$", {
        uri: fundingInstrument.href
    }, function (r) {
        // Check your backend response
        if (r.status === 201) {
            // Your successful logic here from backend ruby
        } else {
            // Your failure logic here from backend ruby
        }
    });
} else {
    // Failed to tokenize, your error logic here
}
}
```

Comment: *But when I balanced.card.create(payload, handleCreditCardResponse) I get undefined* — What is the *exact* error message you are getting? Actually, are you getting an error message at all? It sounds like you are just getting `undefined` as the return value of the `create()` function.

Comment: You are exactly right, balanced.card.create(payload, handleCreditCardResponse) is returning undefined.

Comment: what does `balanced.card.create` in the console get you? what does `balanced.card` get you? what does `balanced` get you? if `balanced` is undefined then it sounds like it may be not actually loading the script. have you tried clearing your browser cache?